# Display Video as Post Thumbnail

Tags: plugins, functions, post-thumbnails

I use the Nova free theme, from the Theme in Progress studio. I would like to display a video like a thumbnail image, as shown in this theme http://themeinprogress.com/demo/sueva/

How can I do this?  I installed a plugin called Video Thumbnails, but didn't work.

Comment: Might have something to do with the way post thumbnails and excerpts are coded into the theme. Otherwise you can ask the plugin author.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source code of the theme the "Montreal By Winter" post (Which I assume is what you're trying to replicate) has the "Video" post format. I'd image selecting that when creating a post will enable you to add a video embed code.